# Reshape dataframe so that matching family members have their own column

Tags: r, tidyverse, data-wrangling

I have a dataframe...

```
df <- tibble(
  id = 1:5, 
  family = c("a","a","b","b","c"), 
  twin = c(1,2,1,2,1), 
  datacol1 = 11:15, 
  datacol2 = 21:25
  )
```

For every twin pair (members of the same family) I need to have a second 'datacol' with the other twins' data. This should only happen for matching twins, so the 5th row (from family "c") should have duplicate columns that are empty.

Ideally, by the end the data would look like the following...

```
df <- tibble(
  id = 1:5, 
  family = c("a","a","b","b","c"), 
  twin = c(1,2,1,2,1), 
  datacol1 = 11:15,
  datacol1.b = c(12,11,14,13,NA),
  datacol2 = 21:25, 
  datacol2.b = c(22,21,24,23,NA)
  )
```

I have added an image to help illustrate what I am trying to get to.

[image]

I would like to be able to do this for all columns or for selected columns and preferably using tidyverse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can also use `mutate_at`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    group_by(family) %>%
    mutate_at(vars(starts_with('datacol')), list(`2` = 
           ~if(n() == 1) NA_integer_ else rev(.)))
# A tibble: 5 x 7
# Groups:   family [3]
#     id family  twin datacol1 datacol2 datacol1_2 datacol2_2
#  <int> <chr>  <dbl>    <int>    <int>      <int>      <int>
#1     1 a          1       11       21         12         22
#2     2 a          2       12       22         11         21
#3     3 b          1       13       23         14         24
#4     4 b          2       14       24         13         23
#5     5 c          1       15       25         NA         NA
```

Comment: I was working on a same approach last night. But I could not figure out that list part. Do you come across this kind of case now and then?

Comment: @jazzurro In this case, when the number of rows are 1 for a group, the OP wanted it to be NA.  But, there would be cases where you wanted to get the `sum` of values by group and if all of them are `NA` and if we use `na.rm = TRUE`, it returns 0.  If the OP wanted it to be `NA`, then we do `if(all(is.na(.))) NA_real_ else sum(., na.rm = TRUE)`

Answer (score 1):

```
cols = c("datacol1", "datacol2")
df %>%
    group_by(family) %>%
    mutate_at(vars(cols), function(x){
        if (n() == 2){
            rev(x)
        } else {
            NA
        }
    }) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    select(cols) %>%
    rename_all(funs(paste0(., ".b"))) %>%
    cbind(df, .)
```

Base R

```
cols = c("datacol1", "datacol2")
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df, df$family), function(x){
    cbind(x, setNames(lapply(x[cols], function(y) {
        if (length(y) == 2) {
            rev(y)
        } else {
            NA
        }}),
        paste0(cols, ".b")))
}))
```